# Adding Labeled Values to JSON

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON response from an API. The JSON response, 'results' is a list containing a number of individual results, called 'routes'.

For each result, within the results JSON response, I wish to add further information, such as what was included in the request that generated this response from the API.

An example of three shortened results ('routes'), within the overall results is shown here:

```
results = 
[({u'routes': [{u'bounds': {u'northeast': {u'lat': value,
                                          u'lng': value},
                           u'southwest': {u'lat': value,
                                          u'lng': value}},
               u'copyrights': u'value',
               u'overview_polyline': {u'points': u’value’},
               u'summary': u’value’,
               u'warnings': [],
               u'waypoint_order': []}],
  u'status': u'OK'}),
({u'routes': [{u'bounds': {u'northeast': {u'lat': value,
                                              u'lng': value},
                               u'southwest': {u'lat': value,
                                              u'lng': value}},
                   u'copyrights': u'value',
                   u'overview_polyline': {u'points': u’value’},
                   u'summary': u’value’,
                   u'warnings': [],
                   u'waypoint_order': []}],
      u'status': u'OK'}),
({u'routes': [{u'bounds': {u'northeast': {u'lat': value,
                                              u'lng': value},
                               u'southwest': {u'lat': value,
                                              u'lng': value}},
                   u'copyrights': u'value',
                   u'overview_polyline': {u'points': u’value’},
                   u'summary': u’value’,
                   u'warnings': [],
                   u'waypoint_order': []}],
      u'status': u'OK'})]
```

I wish to add their respective values. For the above example of 3 results, there are 3 origin coords, such as:

```
origincoords = ['51.41833327,0.115963078', '51.34666046,-0.210947524', '51.39574919,-0.045778021']
```

UPDATE - Thanks to Martineau, I have been able to insert the values correctly. However, I am now curious as to how I could insert into a different location. For example, to achieve:

The end result looking would look like -

```
({u'routes': [{u'bounds': {u'northeast': {u'lat': value,
                                              u'lng': value},
                               u'southwest': {u'lat': value,
                                              u'lng': value},
                               u'origincoords': '51.39574919,-0.045778021'},
                   u'copyrights': u'value',
                   u'overview_polyline': {u'points': u’value’},
                   u'summary': u’value’,
                   u'warnings': [],
                   u'waypoint_order': []}],
      u'status': u'OK'})]
```

Comment: Those "labels" are what is are commonly referred to as the keys associated with the values you want to add to each dictionary in the `results` list.

Comment: This is very useful. I must continue to build my vocabulary. Many thanks for not just the answers, but for the tutoring too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you said you want doesn't quite make sense:

```
({u'routes': [{u'bounds': {u'northeast': {u'lat': value,
                                              u'lng': value},
                               u'southwest': {u'lat': value,
                                              u'lng': value}},
                   u'copyrights': u'value',
                   u'overview_polyline': {u'points': u’value’},
                   u'summary': u’value’,
                   u'warnings': [],
                   u'waypoint_order': []}],
      u'status': u'OK'}
      u'origincoords': '51.39574919,-0.045778021'})]
```

But this does:

```
({u'routes': [{u'bounds': {u'northeast': {u'lat': value,
                                              u'lng': value},
                               u'southwest': {u'lat': value,
                                              u'lng': value}},
                   u'copyrights': u'value',
                   u'overview_polyline': {u'points': u’value’},
                   u'summary': u’value’,
                   u'warnings': [],
                   u'waypoint_order': []}],
      u'status': u'OK',  # NOT the end of the dict
      u'origincoords': '51.39574919,-0.045778021'})]
```

An easy way to get the latter, which uses `izip` (or `zip`), would be:

```
try:
    from itertools import izip
except ImportError:
    izip = zip  # Python 3

origincoords = ['51.41833327,0.115963078',
                '51.34666046,-0.210947524',
                '51.39574919,-0.045778021']

for route, origincoord in izip(results, origincoords):
    route['origincoord'] = origincoord
```

**Update**

If you instead wanted to insert the pairs into the `'bounds'` dictionary inside the first, `[0]`, dictionary in the `'routes'` list of each of the dictionaries in the `results` list, that could be done by using the following:

```
for route, origincoord in izip(results, origincoords):
    route['routes'][0]['bounds']['origincoord'] = origincoord
```

Note that both lists and dictionaries use `[`*`x`*`]` notation to access their contents. The *`x`* must evaluate to an integer index for lists, or a hashable object (e.g. string, integer, tuple, etc) for dictionaries.

Comment: I am indebted. Thank you.

Comment: In the case where I would like to insert the key and value into a different location, within the JSON response, how would I specify this index?

Comment: It depends on what part of the response you want to insert them. At the highest level `results` itself is a list of dictionaries, so to insert another item in that list you could use `results.insert(<index>, <value>)`. To insert (or replace) an entry in one of these upper-most dictionaries in `results` you'd use `results[<index>][<key>] = <value>`. To make it easier to see the structure of the data in the response, try `import json`, then `print(json.dumps(results, indent=4))`.

Comment: Thanks @martineau. Indeed, Ive been able to insert values in that form. But how would I perform the operation above, only for a different location. I wish to insert the key and values, as above (using izip), but in a different location, say, within the 'bounds' dictionary?

Comment: P.S. You might want to turn the `origincoord` string into two floating point values. To do this use `...] = [float(x) for x in origincoord.split(',')]` instead of `...] = origincoord`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one simple way of doing it without any zip

```
for index in range(len(results)):
    results[index][u'origincoords'] = origincoords[index]
```

Comment: Thanks @Parind. How would one change the [index] to insert the values in a different location, for example, ['routes'][0]['legs'][0]

Comment: results[0]["routes"][0]["bounds"]["new_element"] = "new_data"

Answer (score 0):

The zip function returns a list of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences. To add the coordinates in the result you may want to iterate over this list of tuples and assign it in for loop:

```
for result, coord in zip(results, origincoords):
    result[u'origincoords'] = coord
```